# Python OS Library: mkdir and chdir in the same line?

Tags: python

Is there a more concise way to create a new directory and change to that directory than:

```
import os

os.mkdir(my_dir)
os.chdir(my_dir)
```

I know it's just one extra line of code, but I'd like to tighten up if I can.

Comment: Just curious: Why? What's wrong with two lines? If you're using it so much that it bothers you, you can just write a function that calls these two.

Comment: Python is not the first language that comes to mind when you want to save on lines.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow's scope is limited to _practical_, answerable questions. Saving lines at the expense of readability is contrary to the zen of python and understood best practice -- it's inherently impractical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own wrapper around the two functions:

```
import os

def a(b):
    os.mkdir(b)
    os.chdir(b)
```

Now, whenever you want to create a new directory and change to that directory, use

```
a(directory)
```

Also, if you'd really like to achieve that in *one line*, use

```
os.mkdir(you_are_welcome); os.chdir(you_are_welcome)
```

Comment: ... but please don't write 2 statements in one line that.

Answer (score 0):

**`os`** methods related to file and directory manipulation do not return any object, thus they don't allow for *chaining*.

Your best option for this specific case is to embed your methods in a function, as others already said (well your best option is to do nothing imho).

But if you'd like to take this a step further and you're willing to adapt os functionalities to method chaining, you could define a sort of *decorator* that returns the `os` module at the end of the given function:

```
def return_path(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        return os
    return wrapper

os.mkdir = return_path(os.mkdir)
```

This way `os.mkdir()` supports method chaining:

```
os.mkdir(my_dir).chdir(my_dir)
```

This is just a possible way to customize a built-in behaviour through *overriding*; it is definitely an overwork for such a problem.

I suggest you keep your program as a clear and well structured set of instructions.
As a general coding practice, do not sacrifice clarity for the sake of conciseness, e.g. multiple statements on the same line are bad for *PEP8*, and for a good reason.

Answer (score -1):

```py
import os

my_dir = 'test'
[fun(my_dir) for fun in (os.mkdir, os.chdir)]
```

Comment: [Don't use list comprehensions for side-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)

Comment: List comprehensions and loops are fundamentally different things. Please don't try to cram one into the other.